# Xcode Build error after cloning from git: unable to open dependencies file ( another one)

Tags: xcode, build

None of the previous solutions found on stack didn't help me and I've seen there are quite a few.

I've created a SwiftUI project with SPM, developed my app, run it, all good.
I've pushed the code to git so my coworker can work on it too.
After he pulled it and tried to build it he received this

```
error: unable to open dependencies file (/Users/<redacted>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
<redacted>-aqnfbcpbnudmgwajyejjjhfcfagi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/
<redacted>.build/Debug-iphoneos/<redacted>.build/Objects-normal/
arm64/<redacted>-master-emit-module.d) (in target '<redacted>' from project '<redacted>')
```

The solutions i've found said to delete the Derived data folder.
I tried to reproduce the issue on my machine as well, and i've deleted that folder, now my project behaves the same and we're both stuck.

I've checked on my machine and that file doesn't exist.

Not sure what to try anymore.

Xcode 15.0.1

macOS 14.0

Any ideas?

EDIT: If i change the compilation mode to `whole module` it works. But if i let it as `incremental` it fails with the mentioned error

Comment: Try to reset the cache and see if that fixes the issue. I had faced similar issue and resetting cache of the packages helped me to tackle that.

You can reset the package caches by going to File -> Swift Packages -> Reset Package Caches.

Comment: Done that @JobinsJohn , didn t work, unfortunately.